# Function call fails after column renaming (error 42703 "column does not exist")

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-function, postgresql-10

Simple scenario:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (bar int);

INSERT INTO foo VALUES (42);

CREATE FUNCTION baz() RETURNS int AS $$
SELECT bar
FROM foo
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

SELECT baz();
```

This works and returns 42.

I don't like my column naming, so I rename it:

```
ALTER TABLE foo RENAME bar TO qux;
```

But now if I call the function again:

```
SELECT baz();
```

> [42703] ERROR: column "bar" does not exist
>
> SQL function "baz" during inlining

I expected the renaming to "cascade" to function bodies, as PostgreSQL prevents creation of functions with invalid column references.

Do I really have to recreate each function that references the column by its old name? Using version 10.7.

Comment: "*Do I really have to recreate each function that references the column by its old name*" - yes.

Comment: Why does this behavior differ from other references, e.g. foreign keys? Is it documented? I couldn't find it.

Comment: Don't know. But probably because the table definitions are stored internally in a much more structured way than it's for the functions. So it's easier to cascade the rename for the foreign keys.  There's a simple way to fix your current problem though : `ALTER TABLE foo RENAME 
qux TO bar` ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation says that the function body is [a string constant whose meaning depends on the language](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html). This is interpreted at run-time by the language handler, and [the database server has no built-in knowledge about how to interpret the function's source text](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xplang.html).

Consequently PostgreSQL tracks no dependencies, and the function references tables and columns by name rather than by object ID (like views do).

So PostgreSQL cannot automatically change the function body string just because a table column referenced therein in a language whose syntax is unknown to PostgreSQL changes its name.

Comment: Your answer ignores the fact that it's an SQL function, not a procedural one like PL/pgSQL (your second quote specifically targets those), so PostgreSQL *could* be aware of references. It also doesn't let me create an SQL function which references nonexistent columns, so it's at least interpreted at creation time, not only at run-time. I guess it's something that would be possible to handle, but simply wasn't implemented because of the overhead that would incur. Or because no one had time to develop this feature.

Comment: What you say seems logical, but SQL functions are stored as strings like all procedural language functions (`prosrc` in `pg_proc`). The concept behind languages in PostgresSQL is extensibility, and it was designed with function bodies as strings that PostgreSQL knows nothing about. Tracking dependencies would be difficult with that. Of course one could have devised special treatment for SQL functions, but for the sake of a unified design it is better to treat them alike.